# Json - get specific field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to get field **source** from **JSON** but my solution not working !!

this is json:

```
"trailers":{
      "quicktime":[],
      "youtube":[{
                 "name":"BandeAnnonce",
                 "size":"HD",
                 "source":"RqEuaM9Fsrg",
                 "type":"Trailer"
                }]
 }
```

i try to get the **source** :`var link_trailer =  data.trailers[0].youtube[0].source;`
but is not working for me !!

Comment: What is there in your `data` variable?

Comment: **data** is the object json i get the content from url

Answer (score 1):

trailers is object, you don't need to use index.

`var link_trailer =  JSON.parse(data).trailers.youtube[0].source;`

Comment: I try it but trow me this error msg : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'youtube' of undefined

Comment: This means that data object, doesn't contain trailers property. Are you sure that data is right?

Comment: Yes is right am get the content **json** from **url**

Comment: log the data and check, maybe yon need to use response.data. This error occurs when doesn't object contain property

Comment: or if it's not an object at all and is still json string

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
var text = '{' +
    '"trailers": {' +
    '"quicktime": [],' +
    '"youtube": [{' +
    '"name": "BandeAnnonce",' +
    '"size": "HD",' +
    '"source": "RqEuaM9Fsrg",' +
    '"type": "Trailer"' +
    '}]' +
    '}' +
    '}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
var source = obj.trailers.youtube[0].source;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Source field value is :"+source;
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/5387/

Comment: i get the **json**content from **URL** !

Comment: you can also see  source field value from the result area in jsfiddle

Answer (score -2):

Parse json into object first

`var link_trailer =  JSON.parse(data).trailers[0].youtube[0].source`

Comment: trow me this error ! Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @user88057 Probably your JSON isn't valid. It should be in curly braces